# How to add Prerequisite file (.prq) to InstallShield project?

Tags: prerequisites, installshield-2013

I want to add .prq file (already defined prerequisite) to my installer project under Reditributables in InstallShield. I know the default location of prerequisites, `[ISProductFolder]\SetupPrerequisites`. But I'm having some couple of .prq files distributed at different location on my system.

So is there any way to direct import .prq files to my installer project in InstallShield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching on internet, I found the workaround. Using following option you can add prerequisites folder location paths.
In InstallShield,

> Go to Tools tab -> options -> Prerequisites tab

On this tab, mention the prerequisites folder locations separate with comma.
After saving this changes, go to Redistributables section and refresh the prerequisites in right pane. And you will see the prerequisites listed there.